# Using a variable inside a def function

Tags: python

Apologies for the mega noob question but I'm trying to create a string using a defined function with a variable for the parameter

```
def plusone(number):
    return (number + 1)

print('Enter a number')
Userinput = input()
print(' You have entered '+ str(plusone(Userinput)) + ' less 1')
```

I receive this error - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: `Userinput` is a string you have to convert it to `int`

Comment: You need to cast `Userinput` to an int.
like so: `Userinput=int(input())`.